# Modificar contact form 7

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme, contact-form-7

Tengo un tema de wordpress que usa contact form 7, en un formulario tengo esto:
[image: Imagen]

En el campo monto a financiar viene esa cantidad por defecto, pero no se como modificarla, por ejemplo poner una coma $50,000 o cambiar la cantidad.

[image: html] 
Ese es el único código que viene para modificar es solo HTML

Soy nuevo en wordpress y estoy muy perdido.

Comment: De donde viene ese monto?

Comment: No tengo la menor idea, creo que viene de algun JS, pero no se donde esta o como modificarlo, ese HTML es lo único que me permite ver Contact form 7

Comment: Que tema es? quizás si viene con el tema por defecto, en los ajustes debería de poderse cambiar

Comment: Hola, el tema se llama Borrow, pero no podido encontrar donde se pueda modificar. Gracias por el seguimiento.

Comment: Veo que es un tema de pago, con varios Home, en que home se encuentra lo que quieres modificar? Haz intentado verlo directo en el diseñador?